# RubyOnRails - Can't do a where statment in a has_many through relatiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, where-clause

So I'm new to RoR and i can't seem to do a select where statment. These are the following classes:

The models:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :list_categorization
  has_many :category, :through => :list_categorization
end

class ListCategorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :list_id

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :list
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :list_categorizations
  has_many :lists, :through => :list_categorizations
end
```

And what i'm trying to do is to select a list with a given category. I tried to do a simplified version of this in the list_controler with the following code:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

    @lists = List.where("category.id = ?", 2)
  end
end
```

And with the following view:

```
<ul class="lists">
  <%= render @lists%>
</ul>
```

Then the following error apears:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Lists#index_where
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: category.id: SELECT "lists".*
>   FROM "lists"  WHERE (category.id = 2) ORDER BY lists.created_at DESC

What am I doing wrong? Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@lists = Category.find(2).lists
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you tried to do something like this:

```
@lists = List.joins(:categories).where('category.id = 2')
```

You could do:

```
@lists = Category.find(2).lists
```

Comment: It worked that way! Don't know when I should use the where statement but.. thanks!

Comment: When you have a bunch of data, and you want to create a condition to limit the records, just like an SQL statement.
The problem with List.where("category.id = ?", 2) is that you are trying to apply a condition on List objects that is meant for Category objects.
Category.find(2) = Category.where('categories.id = 2')